# Source code of the full OpenDaylight Integration Distribution Bundle

Tags: apache-karaf, opendaylight, karaf-maven-plugin, apache-karaf-feature

My team is using [OpenDaylight 0.11.0](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/integration/opendaylight/0.11.0/) as the basis for a SDN controller. I am wondering how that .tar.gz is built?

I.e., is there a base project on github and a maven command that creates that .tar.gz file?

I am finding so many different opendaylight related modules, features and code bases that I simply can't find the full source code from which the above noted tar.gz is built from. I am thinking it is a combination of many different opendaylight modules, however I am sure there is a parent project that bundles them all together.

My end goal is to build a custom feature for our team that can be `feature:installed` in ODL 0.11.0's karaf console.

We have already followed the [dev guide here](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-sodium/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html), however that base project doesn't contain many of the features available on the ODL 0.11.0 linked at the top. I.e., when you build out that sample project, it doesn't come with the same set of features as the ODL 0.11.0 tar.gz linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, ODL as a whole is just comprised of a bunch of smaller, more specific,
projects. Here is a way to [visualize](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/display/ODL/Projects) it. So you could just clone one
of those projects that does something you want, (e.g., [netconf](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/admin/repos/netconf)) and
build that (mvn clean install). That would build netconf and pull in all the
artifacts of everything it depends on. At the end you would get something you
could run (netconf/karaf/target/assembly/bin/karaf) and then install some
netconf features.

If you want the whole thing, like you'd find by going to the downloads page,
then you can clone our [integration/distribution repo](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/admin/repos/integration/distribution). That will pull
in the artifacts for all of those projects and you could install netvirt
and bgpcep features for example. That build would result in the .tar.gz
file you are referring to.

So, in the end if you want to create some new project you could build
that locally. Then, you would have to update the integration/distribution
project to pull in your new project (probably could just follow how
it's doing it for other projects), then build it. If all goes well, you'd
get the full distribution with all the features including the new one.

Good Luck!

PS. I saw your IRC message, but you had logged out by the time I noticed.
You can also ask for help via our [email lists](https://lists.opendaylight.org/groups).

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how active IRC was and figured if the question was on SOF, it would stick and be easy to go back to and reference. I will check out your advice, thanks!

Comment: I have another question that extend this. Hopefully you can help! Thanks again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060044/install-a-custom-feature-or-module-in-opendaylight