# Install a custom feature or module in Opendaylight?

Tags: opendaylight

I recently created a basic HelloWorld ODL module as [stepped out here](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-sodium/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html), and I am able to make it work. I.e., I can run restful POST commands against it and get my "hello" reply.

```
{
    "output": {
        "greeting": "Hello Andrew"
    }
}
```

Now, what I'd like to do is install this module into the actual ODL as compiled from the [integration distro repos](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/admin/repos/integration/distribution).

The steps I follow are:

1. Successfully create the HelloWorld ODL module and run karaf from within the HelloWorld karaf subfolder
2. Knowing that `mvn install` against the Hello project will publish this module into my local `.m2/repository/org/opendaylight/hello` repo, I move on to the actual ODL integration/distro
3. in the `features/repos/index/pom.xml` file in ODL, I add the following profile:

   ```
   <profile>
       <id>hello</id>
       <activation>
           <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
       </activation>
       <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.opendaylight.hello</groupId>
             <artifactId>features-hello</artifactId>
             <classifier>features</classifier>
             <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
             <type>xml</type>
         </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </profile>
   ```
4. Then I successfully run `mvn install` on ODL and it does not error on that profile. (Note: if I typo anything in that profile section, the `mvn install` will fail)

- I am doing everything to ODL v0.11.0 and Sodium 1.2.0 in my application, so I am sure the versions are correct.

All is said and done, the ODL karaf does fire up and I am able to run rest commands against it... however the same POST command that worked purely against the HelloWorld module does not work in the integrated distro ODL. Instead I get this error message back:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "error": [
            {
                "error-type": "protocol",
                "error-tag": "unknown-element",
                "error-message": "The module named 'hello' does not exist."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In some ways, this question is a bit of an extension to my previous one here: [Source code of the full OpenDaylight Integration Distribution Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942864/source-code-of-the-full-opendaylight-integration-distribution-bundle). So just linking them together here.

Update:
I created an inverse to this question here: [Procedure to add features to OpenDaylight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162068/procedure-to-add-features-to-opendaylight-application).

Note:

- In the `feature:list` section, I do not see Hello listed

Answer (score -1):

ODL Integration distribution does not install any karaf feature by default, so once you start the distribution, check whether your project feature is installed (e.g. feature:list -i). If it is not, just install it (e.g. feature:install ).

Comment: Unfortunately, the "hello" sample feature is not listed in feature:list...

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, but there is probably something small missing that is not bringing your feature in when you build integration/distribution. Try comparing to another project to see if you can figure it out. maybe checkout the aaa project and compare to one of it's features like odl-aaa-cert. BTW, if you find there is some basic step missing in the docs, let us know (email) or even better, you can update the docs yourself and contribute to opendaylight :)

Comment: @jamo I assume you mean copy the structure of this repo https://github.com/opendaylight/aaa/tree/master/aaa-cert and modify it to fit our own module?

Comment: @jamo - put another way, "How do I create a new feature and ensure it is properly listed in the feature:list section of karaf" - I am not able to find the documentation on doing that.

Comment: no, what I mean is to clone the AAA repo then poke around it's configs (e.g., pom.xml files) for how the odl-aaa-cert feature is defined and setup. I know that feature is available in feature:list of a full distribution. You might find something that you missed in your hello project.